# Did the camp mechanics change?

Tags: league-of-legends

When I started jungling, it was common, while stealing a camp, to leave one small creep in the camp, because the camp timer doesn't start until that last creep is cleared.

I just realised, watching worlds, that nobody does that anymore. When stealing a camp, they always full clear it anyway.

Did the mechanics change since Season 3-4, or is it just now more advantageous to full clear the camp over leaving one creep?

Comment: The mechanics of monster spawning has definitely not changed. If there's one small mob left, the whole camp doesn't respawn. However, jungling items and experience/gold gains have changed many times since season 3, so that's probably part of why taking the whole camp is more common now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The old camps, like wraiths etc... it was common to leave one small creep at the opponent's camp because it hurts the enemy jungler more. But now since the EXP is shared across all the creeps upon clearing the camp instead of just the big one, it actually hurts you more than the enemy jungler.

Comment: So that strategy died because now there's an XP bonus to clear the full camp?

Comment: I mean the EXP that was originally only in the big creep is now shared across all three of the creeps, so losing that one creep every time just to cause your opponent a few seconds of inconvenience is not worth it.

Comment: @spyang302 You also used to have to compromise the fact that by not clearing the camp, you don't get the spawn timer unless you keep vision on it.  If you clear the camp yourself, you can be ready for the next spawn (if your timing/attention to timing is good).

Comment: It's also worth noting that the red/blue buff camps no longer have smaller creeps to leave, and nobody really cares if you don't kill the last murkwolf.

Comment: @Exal probably hit it right on the spot. You usually steal a blue or red. Letting that creep live kept that buff out of the game longer. These small creeps on the buff are not there anymore; so you can't leave one to time out the camp. For small camps, not taking all of the advantage will penalise you in the long run (less XP and Gold for running into the enemy jungle) so you take it all making the risk more valuable.